# MYSQL order by time am/pm

Tags: mysql, time, sql-order-by

I have a row in a table which holds the time of day in am/pm format e.g.

```
timeField
---------
9.00am
10.00pm
7.00am 
etc...
```

Is there a way in mysql to order these values?

Comment: `I have a row in a table which holds the time of day in am/pm format` This was a bad design decision in my opinion...

Comment: it is just the way someone else built the database - and it has stumped me at present :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this by using [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function in MySQL:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10.00pm','%h.%i%p');
```

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(timeField,'%h.%i%p');
```

## Example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da5f9/1)

Comment: I think you mean ORDER BY, not SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

In order to order it you need to format the date field fist.

try this

```
SELECT COl1, COl2, DATE_FORMAT(yourdate, '%k:%i:%s') AS mydate
FROM your_table
ORDER BY mydate
```

Enjoy

Comment: Just tried  ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(time_id,'%h.%i%p') DESC which seems to work

Answer (score 1):

**Use Below Query**

```
select * from 'Your Table Name' order by str_to_date('yourtimefield', '%l:%i %p');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Name
```

This put everything in order for me: Alphabetized, Dates and Time