# How to sort MySQLi table by time in ASC order

Tags: mysqli, time, varchar

I want to display my ***table*** according to their ***time*** in ***ascending*** order.

***table sample:***

```
+------+----------+-----+
|  id  |   time   | val |
+------+----------+-----+
|  1   | 01:22 AM |  a  |
+------+----------+-----+
|  2   | 03:12 PM |  b  |
+------+----------+-----+
|  3   | 07:21 AM |  c  |
+------+----------+-----+
|  4   | 01:52 PM |  d  |
+------+----------+-----+
|  5   | 07:40 PM |  e  |
+------+----------+-----+
```

it should be arrange from - ***AM to PM*** order

```
a - 01:22 AM
c - 07:21 AM
d - 01:52 PM
b - 03:12 PM
e - 07:40 PM
```

***table*** is not in **date- time** format it's only in **varchar**

Comment: your database is called mysql, not mysqli

Comment: This answer, from Omesh, should help you;

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12952663/297243

Answer (score 0):

`table is not in date- time format it's only in varchar` - that's your problem.

Change it to [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) format and everything will be sorted all right