# to sort time ( AM / PM ) in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing problem with sorting according to AM / PM.

Here is my table data

```
login_time
1:30 PM
11:00 AM
10:00 AM
12:30 PM
10:00 PM
11:10 AM
12:20 PM
3:40 PM
2:20 PM
```

I want result as:

```
10:00 AM
11:00 AM
11:10 AM
12:20 PM
12:30 PM
1:30  PM
2:20 PM
3:30 PM
```

Comment: I hope you're storing your times as `TIME`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP`, and not as `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL order by time am/pm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952608/mysql-order-by-time-am-pm)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you haven't shown us your SELECT query so I'm taking wild guesses, but I would think you probably have something like this:

```
SELECT login_time
FROM my_table
```

and you need to have this:

```
SELECT login_time
FROM my_table
ORDER BY login_time
```

That is, of course, assuming that login_time is of the appropriate type `time`.

Answer (score 1):

If `login_time` is stored as a time, you can just do:

```
order by login_time
```

If `login_time` is stored as a string, you can do:

```
order by str_to_date(login_time, '%h:%i %p')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving datetime data with proper data-type and this will create issues like you are having now. Your data is saved as `varchar` and they are not proper date or time.

However in your case you may try as below, i.e. first convert it to a real time and then get the seconds and then order by.

```
select * from table_name
order by time_to_sec(str_to_date(login_time,'%h:%i %p'))
```

Without `time_to_sec` function should work too.

```
 order by str_to_date(login_time,'%h:%i %p')
```