# Selecting time ignoring A.M and P.M in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, time

I have a select statement that selects the time, and order by the time asc, but it seems to be ignoring the A.M and P.M part. How would I fix that?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(max(time),'%h:%i:%s %p') AS mytimestr FROM currentChat WHERE date = '$date' ORDER BY mytimestr ASC
```

**Result:**

```
1:00 A.M
2:00 P.M
3.00 A.M
4.00 P.M
```

**Need Result:**

```
1:00 A.M
3.00 A.M
2:00 P.M
4.00 P.M
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL order by time am/pm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952608/mysql-order-by-time-am-pm)

Comment: `max(time)` - I doubt that you get a result set with more than one record with _that_ query.

Comment: are you storeing proper date\time field types?

Comment: @Dagon Yes, the date are stored as date variables, and the time as time variables.

Comment: @Dagon The stored time is in 24 hour format, and does not include the A.M and P.M part.

Comment: never seen it order by incorrectly if its in the right format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `time` column is a MySQL `TIME` datatype, as I suspect it is from the way you call `DATE_FORMAT`, then you don't need to `ORDER BY` your `mytimestr` expression. You can simply order by the `time` field itself to get the records in chronological order.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(max(time),'%h:%i:%s %p') AS mytimestr
FROM currentChat
WHERE date = '$date'
ORDER BY max(time) ASC
```

I'm not sure whether you intended to have `MAX(...)` without a `GROUP BY` - this will only return one row making the `ORDER BY` a little bit redundant but perhaps you only gave a portion of your query.

Comment: Yes. I only gave the relevant part of the query. Thanks, this works.